# How to restrict element content and define attributes simultaneously in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I am trying to add a restriction in a XSD to a complex type element. I am trying to use the `minInclusive` value="0.00034" and `maxInclusive` value="99" to add bounds when I verify an XML file using XML Notepad 2007. I have searched the archives and having a hard time with the syntax of where to add the restriction. Any help is appreciated.

```
<xsd:element name="R-value">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Resistance of material</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:decimal">
                <xsd:attribute name="unit" type="resistanceUnitEnum" use="required"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a type to cover your restriction, and then extend that type to add in your attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:simpleType name="R-value-content-type">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
      <xsd:minInclusive value="0.00034"/>
      <xsd:maxInclusive value="99"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

  <xsd:element name="R-value">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Resistance of material</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="R-value-content-type">
          <xsd:attribute name="unit" use="required"/>
        </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>  
</xsd:schema>
```